# Can someone look through this minecraft command and find the missing or extra curly bracket/s?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, technical-issues, minecraft-redstone

I'm just trying to find the error spot, and I need a little help looking through it. Please respond with the location of the missing curly bracket/s or just put them in and copy and paste the command in your reply. Thanks for any help.

```
/summon Villager ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:Compactor,Visible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,Silent:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:emerald,Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 1 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["9 Emeralds."},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 1 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["9 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 2 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["81 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 2 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["81 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 3 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["729 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 3 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["729 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["6561 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 4 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["6561 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 4 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["59,049 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 5 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["59,049 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 5 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 6 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["531,441 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 6 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["531,441 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 7 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["4,782,969 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 7 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["4,782,969 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 8 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["43,046,721 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 8 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["43,046,721 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 9 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["387,420,489 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 9 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["387,420,489 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 10 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["3,486,784,401 Emeralds.","No further compactions possible."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finding a typo.

Comment: Hi Giga!  You might want to look at getting a copy of Notepad ++ if you're curly hunting. It's one of the better freeware out there for highlighting syntax.

Comment: At a glance in Notepad++, your ending curly brace matches with your Recipies command.  You're missing an end curly brace somewhere because it thinks CustonName doesn't have an end, but I don't know nearly enough minecraft command to know exactly which one is missing or where it should be.

Answer (score 2):

```
Name:"Tier 1 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["9 Emeralds."},Count:1
```

`Lore` is correctly started with a square bracket, `[`, but then you've only ended with a curly one, `}`. You need `]}}` here to end the `Lore` list, the `Display` compound tag, then the `tag` compound tag.

Fixed command:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:Compactor,Visible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,Silent:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:emerald,Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 1 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["9 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 1 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["9 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 2 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["81 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 2 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["81 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 3 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["729 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 3 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["729 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["6561 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 4 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["6561 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 4 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["59,049 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 5 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Lore:["59,049 Emeralds."],Name:"Tier 5 Compacted Emerald"}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 6 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["531,441 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 6 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["531,441 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 7 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["4,782,969 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 7 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["4,782,969 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 8 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["43,046,721 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 8 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["43,046,721 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 9 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["387,420,489 Emeralds."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 9 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["387,420,489 Emeralds."]}},Count:9},sell:{id:emerald,tag:{display:{Name:"Tier 10 Compacted Emerald",Lore:["3,486,784,401 Emeralds.","No further compactions possible."]}},Count:1},rewardExp:false,maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

I'd recommend using a generator in the future, or writing the command bit-by-bit and testing as you go along.

Comment: Also, the CustomName is a string, and needs quotes around it

Comment: @DanielG Not necessary unless you use characters such as brackets or quotation marks inside of the string.